# Google Sheets IF (in multiple cells) text contains, then return the text

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

Please help!

If A2, B2, or C2 contains text (ANY TEXT... nothing specific), then return the text of that cell in D2.

I've tried several things, but I cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

If more than one contains text what should happen??

With `=IFNA(FILTER(A2:C2,ISTEXT(A2:C2)))` you can search through them and then join them with `=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IFNA(FILTER(A2:C2,ISTEXT(A2:C2))))`

If you need it as an array, you can do:

`=BYROW(A2:C,LAMBDA(each,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IFNA(FILTER(each,ISTEXT(each))))))`

Answer (score 0):

use in cell D2:

```
=A2&B2&C2
```

you can add spaces if you need:

```
=TRIM(A2&" "&B2&" "&C2)
```